# website upload file to directory

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to create website to upload a file into a directory inside called "Uploads". I was wondering how to do this with HTML, JavaScript and/or PHP. I am new to website building. Thanks.

Comment: Hi! I'd strongly suggest that you had a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better idea of how SO works, SO is not a teaching portal.

Comment: This can easily be researched online. Question is far too broad as it stands for SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form id="form_request_file" method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table align="center" width="525" border="0">

        <label for="uploaded" class="control-label col-sm-2">Upload File</label>
        <input id="uploaded" name="uploaded" type="file"/>
        <input value="Submit" name="submit" type="submit"/>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if (isset($_FILES['uploaded'])) {
    $path = "uploaded_docs/";
    $file_name = basename($_FILES['uploaded']['name']);
    $target = $path . $file_name;
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploaded"]["tmp_name"], $target)) {
      echo $file_name . " was uploaded";
    } else {
      echo "Could not upload";
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: While I understand that it's up to each individual user to decide whether to answer or not, I wish you wouldn't provide a answer to questions like this one, it breeds the ill effect of people continuing to post off-topic and poor questions, despite of SO's rules, because why care for the rules when you'll get a answer either ways?